# How exactly do we apply for the $27,000 which is being offered to move to Italy?

Tags: europe, italy, working-visas

According to this we can move to certain small villages in Italy in exchange for 700 EUR per month for 3 year, ***if*** we agree to start a business there to help the locals:
https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/molise-italy-pay-to-move/index.html

However I have searched for hours for the application form or process, and only find articles saying the same things over and over again (the same things that are already mentioned in the CNN article). How do we apply? Maybe the problem is that I'm only searching using an English search engine?

Comment: This looks like a question for our sister site [expatriates.se].

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I did not know that this sister site existed! Can we please get it migrated?

Comment: Fair warning: maybe *this* offer is real, but a similar offer in a different village in a different region in 2016 turned out to just be "a suggestion" (or, I suspect, a publicity stunt that went too far...) and was never enacted AFAIK https://www.thelocal.it/20170511/italian-village-retracts-offer-of-money-to-move-there-after-receiving-thousands-of-requests

Answer (score 9):

What an interesting challenge!

I looked at the CNN article, which mentioned "Counselor" Antonio Tedeschi. The word "Counselor" sounds like the position held by a local government official. There were too many towns to review, so I searched for the region "Molise," which might be similar to what we know as a county, and could explain how the offer could include many little towns.

The Molise government has a [webpage.](http://consiglio.regione.molise.it/) I can't read Italian very well, but Google Chrome will translate it automatically on the fly. Drilling down yielded a link for "Counselors," rather like Supervisors or Councilmembers.

Presto! There was [Antonio Tedeschi's page](http://consiglio.regione.molise.it/node/4305), including his email: *cons.tedeschi@regione.molise.it*

Write to him!